# Why is this code printing output as "True" although it should print "False"?

Tags: c++

Why is this code printing output as "True" although it should print "False"?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int arr[4][4] = {{2, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 1, 4, 3}, {3, 4, 1, 2}, {4, 3, 2, 1}};

    bool value = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i][j] != arr[i][j + 1]
                value = true;
            else
                value = false;
                break;
        }
    }

    if (value == true)
        cout << "True" << endl;
    else
        cout << "False" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should probably use brackets on your `else` statement

Comment: Your `break` is not indented correctly. If you correct the indentation (maybe using auto formatting), then you'll probably spot the bug.

Comment: Unrelated, but you have a potential overflow when `j == 3`.

Comment: 1) arr[i][j + 1] is undefined when j = 3   2)The closing ')' on that if statement   3) The else braces like what others are saying.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your `break` statement is not inside of the `else` statement. You need to use curly braces with else blocks that have more than one statement inside them.

```
else {
    value = false;
    break;
}
```

Comment: "*You need to use curly braces with else blocks that have more than one statement inside them*" - more accurately, with *any block statement*, that includes `if`, `else`, `for`, `while`, `do`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing curly braces on your `else` block, so your inner `for` loop always `break`s on the 1st iteration regardless of the result of the `if` statement:

```cpp
else
{ // <-- add this
    value = false;
    break;
} // <-- add this
```

Also, you are not breaking the outer loop if the inner loop breaks.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int arr[4][4] = {{2, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 1, 4, 3}, {3, 4, 1, 2}, {4, 3, 2, 1}};

    bool value = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i][j] != arr[i][j + 1])
            {
                value = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (value)
            break;
    }

    if (value)
        cout << "True" << endl;
    else
        cout << "False" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Or:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int arr[4][4] = {{2, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 1, 4, 3}, {3, 4, 1, 2}, {4, 3, 2, 1}};

    bool value = false;

    for (int i = 0; (i < 4) && !value; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; (j < 4) && !value; j++)
        {
            value = (arr[i][j] != arr[i][j + 1]);
        }
    }

    if (value)
        cout << "True" << endl;
    else
        cout << "False" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Or, move the looping logic to another function that you can `return` from when needed:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool findIt(int **arr, int rows, int cols)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i][j] != arr[i][j + 1])
                return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[4][4] = {{2, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 1, 4, 3}, {3, 4, 1, 2}, {4, 3, 2, 1}};

    bool value = findIt(arr, 4, 4);
    if (value)
        cout << "True" << endl;
    else
        cout << "False" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```